# How to hide html.actionlink button given a condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var permission in item.Permissions)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => permission)
                    <br/>
                }

           </td>
           <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRole", > "Roles", new { RoleID = item.RoleID}, null) // i want when RoleID = 1, it will > hide the button
                @{ if (item.RoleID == 1) // this is the condition
                    {
                        @:style = "display:none"
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please try to format your code a bit better next time.. Also, why not simply put `Html.ActionLink()` inside your if statement?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/wlEd0

Comment: You can give you ActionLink some ID like this - <%= Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "SomeAction", "SomeController",
         null, new {id = "someID" }) %> 

and hide using JQ inside you condition

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, declare the style property on your HTML Attribute via ActionLink parameter:

```
@if (item.RoleID == 1)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRole", "Roles", new { RoleID = item.RoleID}, null) 
}
else
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRole", "Roles", new { RoleID = item.RoleID }, new { @style = "display:none" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use something this

```
@if (item.RoleID == 1) { 
   @Html.ActionLink(item.marketGroupName, "Index", new { id = 
  item.marketGroupID });
}
```